# Query the DocDB based on document children value in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, azure

I have the DocumentDB like below in my Azure CosmosDB collection.

```
{
     "TemplateID": "73",
     "TemplateName": "Test -template",
     "Read": [{
                "devicename": "",
                "timestamp": "2017-09-19T21:05:12.8550708+05:30",
                "value": "038452735329RIV5"
              },
              {
                "devicename": "",
                "timestamp": "2017-09-19T21:05:12.8550708+05:30",
                "value": "038452735330RIV5"
              },
             ],
    "eventTime": "2017-09-19T21:05:18.7954106+05:30",
}

{
     "TemplateID": "73",
     "TemplateName": "Test -template",
     "Read": [{
                "devicename": "",
                "timestamp": "2017-09-19T21:05:12.8550708+05:30",
                "value": "019452755319RIV5"
              },
              {
                "devicename": "",
                "timestamp": "2017-09-19T21:05:12.8550708+05:30",
                "value": "138452715310RIV5"
              },
             ],
    "eventTime": "2017-09-19T21:05:18.7954106+05:30",
}
```

I need to get the document in following structure by querying the  `value` node of `Read` array from the document(for example if i enter the code `038452735329RIV5`), i need the following output,

```
{
    "TemplateID": "73",
    "TemplateName": "Test -template",
    "eventTime": "2017-09-19T21:05:18.7954106+05:30",
}
```

I tried the following query,

```
var docs = _documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(DocumentPath, queryOptions).Where(x => x.Read.value == code)                 .AsDocumentQuery();
```

I am not getting the required document. I am getting null as doc, but document exist in AzureDB.

Can any one please check and help me on how to query this.

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with Azure, but you might want to try `x.Read.Contains(code)` or `x.Read.Any(read => read == code)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#BuiltinFunctions) build-in function in documentdb.

It could check the values in array.

More details, you could refer to below query.

```
SELECT c.TemplateID,c.TemplateName,c.eventTime FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Read, { 'value': '038452735329RIV5' }
```

The result:

[image]

C# codes:

```
        string EndpointUrl = "xxxxxx";

        string PrimaryKey = "xxxxxxxx";

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };

        var familyQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<test>(
       UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "coll1"), "SELECT c.TemplateID,c.TemplateName,c.eventTime FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Read, { 'value': '038452735329RIV5' }, true)", queryOptions).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]